# What is the correct assertion to use for an expected value?

Tags: java, junit

I'm learning to use Junit. I wrote a method which generates a number strictly less than xX.

I want to test it using Junit. Not sure which assertion to use as the expected is based on xX and I don't see any comparison assertions.

```
// within the Junit test class
ClassA a = new ClassA();

@Test
void randomTest(){
    assertEquals( ? ,a.getValue(5));
}


public int getValue(int xX){
    // returns an integer less than xX
    return (int) (Math.random() * xX);
}
```

Comment: `assertTrue(a.getValue(5) < 5);`

Comment: I can't look up the exact syntax, but you should look into hamcest matchers. `assertThat(a.getValue(5), Matchers.lessThan(5))`. If it falls, you'll get a nicer error message that assertTrue will give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `assertTrue` like `assertTrue(a.getValue(5)<5);`

```
public static void assertTrue(boolean condition)
```

> Asserts that a condition is true. If it isn't it throws an AssertionError without a message.